# How to calculate the distance between 2 distributions plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using `displot` to plot the distributions between `2` sets of data. I use the following code:

```
def plot_distributions(y, Z, filename=None):
    graph, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4), sharey=False)

    legend={'race': ['black','white'],
            'sex': ['female','male']}

    for idx, attr in enumerate(Z.columns):
        for attr_val in [0, 1]:
            ax = sns.distplot(y[Z[attr] == attr_val], hist=False, 
                              kde_kws={'shade': False,},
                              label='{}'.format(legend[attr][attr_val]), 
                              ax=axes[idx])

        if idx == 0 or idx==1:
            ax.set_xlim(0,1)
            ax.set_yticks([])
            ax.set_title("{}".format(attr))

            ax.set_ylabel('Prediction Distribution')
        ax.set_xlabel(r'$P({{income>50K}}|z_{{{}}})$'.format(attr))

    if filename is not None:
        plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
    return graph

graph = plot_distributions(y_pred, Z_test, filename='img.png')
```

This gives me the following result:
[image]

Normally, the 2 plots should be closer to each other.

What is the best way to calculate the distance between those 2 plots ?

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of "distances" for distributions. Mathematically it is called metric for functions.

- One option to use is the maximum difference. `Max(|a(x)-b(x)|)`
- Another is to calculate the overall integral/sum of all differences `Sum(|a(x_i)-b(x_i)|)`
- The second can be more generalized when integrating over a power of the absolute distances

Furthermore, it seems you are dealing with statistical distributions, so you probably should consider statistical tests. For example a kind of rang test like [Wilcox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). But be sure to meet the criteria for that specific test.